# Actions in LoadRunner do not execute code within, for some of the random users

Tags: loadrunner

I am running LR script which has multiple actions, called in particular order based on business process we have. What I see in logs, when I run tests for multiple iterations is, few actions do not execute code within them, for couple of users after first iteration. It only says 'Starting Action' and right then there will be 'Ending Action'. Below is the sample entry from log.

> SELL02.c(354): lr_think_time: 6.71 seconds (recorded think time was 10.00 seconds).   [MsgId: MMSG-15947]
>
> Starting action Login2.    [MsgId: MMSG-15919]
>
> Ending action Login2.  [MsgId: MMSG-15918]
>
> Starting action BUY06. [MsgId: MMSG-15919]
>
> Ending action BUY06.   [MsgId: MMSG-15918]
>
> Starting action Logout.    [MsgId: MMSG-15919]
>
> Ending action Logout.  [MsgId: MMSG-15918]
>
> Ending iteration 1.    [MsgId: MMSG-15965]

Note: This does not happen to any particular users, but it is random. In a test, it can happen to couple of users, in next test it will be different users.
It would be really helpful if anyone knows the reason why it happens and knows how to fix it.

Sorry I missed the details:
LR version: 12.53
Protocol: Web
OS: Windows 10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please update the question with LR version, OS and script protocols. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Buzzy, I have added the details. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the details. I asked around and we never encountered a similar case before so please open an official case with our support team and they will handle it from there. Sorry.

Comment: Sure Buzzy. Thank you :)